# Unable to create DepthCameraSensor when launching in remote computer

Tags: kinect

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I am launching my simulation on a remote computer and setting my ROS_MASTER_URI to it.
To avoid walking to the remote computer (which is at the other side of the room) I connect remotely (ssh) to it an launch the simulation there. Since I do not need the rendering, just the simulation, I use gzserver.

However, when I launch the world with gzserver remotely I get the following error:

> gzserver my_world_with_a_kinect.world

```
[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.100.106
[Err] [RenderEngine.cc:680] Can't open display: 
[Wrn] [RenderEngine.cc:92] Unable to create X window. Rendering will be disabled 
[Err] [DepthCameraSensor.cc:78] Unable to create DepthCameraSensor. Rendering is disabled.
```

Testing with rviz, I see nothing. The depth camera topics are not even created.

However, if I move to the remote computer and execute the same command everything works OK.

I know that been a remote connection, you don't have the Xs unless you connect with ssh -X .
My computer is a Mac and does not have the Xs. Some people suggested me to install Xs but I cannot (for several reasons).

Additionally, I am running other remote simulations and evn if I get the 'Can't open display' error message, everything works fine.

The question is: how can I make the kinect work properly in such a remote environment?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8065/unable-to-create-depthcamerasensor-when-launching-in-remote-computer/) by [Ricardo Tellez](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1118/ricardo-tellez/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 78 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I finally found the solution to this problem.

The solution is to use the Xvfb with some specific parameters.

First, install Xvfb

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

Then, start xvfb with the following parameters:

```
Xvfb -shmem -screen 0 1280x1024x24
```

Finally, launch gzserver exporting the DISPLAY to the one created by xvfb:

```
DISPLAY=:0 gzserver <your options here>
```

And that is all!
Happy remote simulation!

---

Originally posted by [Ricardo Tellez](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1118/ricardo-tellez/) with karma: 78 on 2015-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2015-03-23**:
Awesome. Thanks for sharing the solution.